# How to calculate shortest path with matrix operation in R?

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix, floyd-warshall

I've an adjacent matrix representing a graph.

```
M

   1  2  3  4...

   1  -  1  3  2
   2  1  -  3  1
   3  4  2  -  3
   .
   .
```

I want to perform Floyd's algorithm to calculate the shortest path between each pair of vertices.

And I can definitely iterate over them in a O(N3) complexity.

```
for ( i in 1 : n )
  for ( j in 1 : n )
    for ( k in 1 : n )
      Floyd...
```

However when n = 10^3, R will not stand the iteration. So I'm looking for ways to perform floyd algorithm in matrix operations.

## Additional Reference

Thereotically, we can refer to [MIT Isomap mat file](http://web.mit.edu/cocosci/isomap/code/Isomap.m).

But I'm still confused at **how to perform "repmat" in R**, which replicate the mat several times.

```
%%%%% Step 2: Compute shortest paths %%%%%
disp('Computing shortest paths...'); 

% We use Floyd's algorithm, which produces the best performance in Matlab. 
% Dijkstra's algorithm is significantly more efficient for sparse graphs, 
% but requires for-loops that are very slow to run in Matlab.  A significantly 
% faster implementation of Isomap that calls a MEX file for Dijkstra's 
% algorithm can be found in isomap2.m (and the accompanying files
% dijkstra.c and dijkstra.dll). 

tic; 
for k=1:N
     D = min(D,repmat(D(:,k),[1 N])+repmat(D(k,:),[N 1])); 
     if ((verbose == 1) & (rem(k,20) == 0)) 
          disp([' Iteration: ', num2str(k), '     Estimated time to completion: ', num2str((N-k)*toc/k/60), ' minutes']); 
     end
end
```

Comment: I suggest downloading the source code for the spa package and seeing how they did it.

Comment: Have you looked at the `allShortestPaths` function in the e1071 package?

Comment: @Frank Exactly. It takes in adj matrix and computes all shortest path. Please leave an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked me to leave an answer.  I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, though.  You should visit the help page for `allShortestPaths`.  It looks pretty straightforward to use the function, which can take in a square matrix and find the shorest paths.

the code for `allShortestPaths` in the package `e1071` is as follows

```
function (x) 
{
x <- as.matrix(x)
x[is.na(x)] <- .Machine$double.xmax
x[is.infinite(x) & x > 0] <- .Machine$double.xmax
if (ncol(x) != nrow(x)) 
    stop("x is not a square matrix")
n <- ncol(x)
z <- .C("e1071_floyd", as.integer(n), double(n^2), as.double(x), 
    integer(n^2), PACKAGE = "e1071")
z <- list(length = matrix(z[[2]], n), middlePoints = matrix(z[[4]] + 
    1, n))
z$length[z$length == .Machine$double.xmax] <- NA
z
}
<environment: namespace:e1071>
```

for more information, check out the help page.

Comment: Is there any function doing the same thing as 'allShortestPaths' but for no square matrix?